# Why does Mercurial need to talk to the server, to list outgoing (non-pushed) commits?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

When I type `hg outgoing`, I get a response like this:

```
comparing with ssh://server:1234/path/to/repo
```

and a delay while it communicates over the network.

Why is this network traffic necessary? Is there something fundamental about Mercurial which means it can't remember which commits have been pushed, and which haven't?

Is there an alternative command which can give me similar information without having to communicate over the network?

Comment: It can't possibly know which changesets are in which remote repository without asking the remote repository. What if you pulled changes from the local repo to another one and then pushed to your server from that repo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Mercurial is a distributed system, there are multiple ways for your changes to get from your local repo to the remote repo.

For example:

- it is possible for someone to pull changes from you and then push those changes to the remote repo
- you could actually just copy your local repo using whatever operating system you have and Mercurial would be totally unaware of that.  You could then push the changes in this copy to the remote repo.

However, if you have Mercurial 2.1 or later you can use `hg phase` to determine which changesets have been pushed. Assuming you don't use `hg phase` to change the status of any changesets then the changesets with a phase of `draft` or `secret` have not been pushed and those with a phase of `public` have. Use

```
$ hg log -r "not public()"
```

to see unpublished changesets.

It won't catch the two examples I gave above but it will probably be good enough if you just want to know which changesets you have not pushed.

Look [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#phases) or check `hg help phases` for instructions on how to work with phases.

Answer (score 3):

A mercurial repository can potentially connect with multiple other repositories. So, I guess it needs to make sure the changes that weren't pushed from your repository, didn't arrive from another repository already.